# How to distinguish a Template Type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, types

I have a template class, and would like to write a member method that's able to recognize what kind of type the template has been instantiated to.

I need to create a string identifier containing the following information on the type:

- bit depth
- signed or unsigned
- floating point or int or char

The method should return a string composed in the following way:

> string: (BIT_DEPTH)-(U|S)-(C|I|F)
>
> BIT_DEPTH -> is the number of bits used to represent type
>
> U | S -> describes if type is signed or unsigned
>
> C | I | F -> describes if type is char int or floating point

I thought of a way to find to bit depth:

```
int bitDepth = sizeof(TemplateType) * 8;
```

is it ok?

But have no idea on how to find the other information I need, unless a `switch-case` statement like the following is ok (but don't think so):

```
THE FOLLOWING IS PSEUDO CODE THAT YOU SHOULD HELP ME EXPRESS IN A CORRECT SYNTAX

switch(TemplateType){

    case signed: ...;
    case unsigned: ...;

    default: ...;

}
```

My questions are two:

- is bit depth calculation correct?
- is the `switch-case` statement a good idea? (if yes can you please correct the syntax)

Comment: Have you considered run time type identification? (RTTI?) and/or dynamic_cast or reinterpret_cast and testing the result somehow?

Comment: @therobyouknow actually no, I'm quite new to this stuff. Can you point me out some directions?

Comment: The only solution is as stated above RTTI, but personally I would recommend redesigning and taking advantage of polymorphism

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bit calculation is OK, but can be improved by using `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit).

To get the other information, you can use [`<type_traits>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926129.aspx), specifically:

- `std::is_signed` / `std::is_unsigned`
- `std::is_integral` / `std::is_floating_point`

Note that floating point types are always signed, but `std::is_signed` will return false, because it tests if the type is a signed *integer*.

Also note that `char` is just another integral type, so there's no standard type trait to specifically test that, but you can use a simple `std::is_same<T, char>`.

In code, this might look like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <climits> // CHAR_BIT

template<class T>
void f(){
  std::cout << sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT << "-";
  if(std::is_integral<T>::value){
     if(std::is_signed<T>::value)
       std::cout << "S";
     else
       std::cout << "U";
     std::cout << "-";
     if(std::is_same<T, char>::value)
       std::cout << "C";
     else
       std::cout << "I";
  }else if(std::is_floating_point<T>::value){
    std::cout << "S-F";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/K7kfN)

Note that `bool` counts as unsigned integer, but that is easily fixed. Also note that the compiler will spew a bunch of warnings regarding "conditional expression is constant", so that can be improved, but this should suffice as a demonstration.

Comment: Wow, you were just GREAT!thks so much!

Comment: @Xeo: Great answer. +1 for correctness, succinctness and just lots of great info in general.

Comment: @Xeo I'm getting an error from compiler saying `error: ‘is_integral’ is not a member of ‘std’`. Are `<type_traits>` supported by g++ version 4.5.2?

Comment: @Matteo: You need to pass `-std=c++0x` to g++, since `<type_traits>` is a C++11 header.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Xeo's answer, you can remove those warnings by doing this all at compile time with `std::enable_if`. For instance:

```
template<typename T>
inline
typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value, char>::type
sign() { return 'S'; }

template<typename T>
inline
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value, char>::type
sign() { return 'U'; }
```

One thing to look out for, though, is that `is_signed` for `float` is `false`!

Comment: Or you could make a `char sign[2] = { 'U', 'S' };` and index with `sign[std::is_signed<T>::value]`.

Comment: I just noticed that you'd rather use `std::is_unsigned` and flip the array elements. That way, the result will be correct even for floating point types.