# Can stdint's int8_t exist on an architecture that does not have 8-bit bytes?

Tags: c, architecture, types

[Apparently there are architectures that don't have 8-bit bytes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit)

It would seem that such architectures would preclude the existence of an `int8_t` (defined in `stdint.h`) type since C, from my understanding, cannot create datatypes smaller than a `CHAR_BIT`.

That said, the [IEEE stdint.h def](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html) seems to require that such a type exist (along with others), only allowing for the 64-bit to not exist on architectures that do not support it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: is there such an architecture still in existence? i doubt systems before 8080 or some rare doesnt support 8bit as a byte. But havent seen, read about such system lately

Comment: Yep. I'm working on an architecture with a 16-bit char and a int8_t exists (and doesn't overflow / wrap the way you'd expect it to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: As @JasonD points out in the comments below, the linked page states at the end;

> As a consequence of adding int8_t, the following are true:
>
> - A byte is exactly 8 bits.
> - {CHAR_BIT} has the value 8, {SCHAR_MAX} has the value 127, {SCHAR_MIN} has the value -128, and {UCHAR_MAX} has the value 255.

In other words, the linked IEEE page *does not apply to architectures with other byte lengths than 8*. This is in line with POSIX which requires 8 bit char.

-- Before edit --

<strike>The explanation is in a note on the [page you linked to](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html);</strike>

> The "width" of an integer type is the number of bits used to store its value in a pure binary system; **the actual type may use more bits than that** (for example, a 28-bit type could be stored in 32 bits of actual storage)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! *facepalm* Thanks!

Comment: I do not think this is correct - the intN_t types are specified as being *exact* width types, with no padding, etc.

Comment: @JasonD You may be correct, but the linked page (that extends the C standard) is slightly fuzzy about the length requirements for the _exact_ types. It _requires_ that uint8_t exists with width 8, but does not seem to require that it be stored in exactly 8 bits, just that it has the correct range. On the other hand, [C99](http://web.archive.org/web/20050207010641/http://dev.unicals.com/papers/c99-draft.html#7.18) declares all exact length types as entirely optional, only requiring some `least` and `fast` types.

Comment: However it states this seperately to the definition of int8_t, and moreover it states that a consequence of defining int8_t is that a byte is necessarily then strictly defined as 8-bits. So it is mututally exclusive with having a non 8-bit byte, the presence of which was a prerequisite for the question... :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because an architecture doesn't handle 8-bit bytes natively, doesn't preclude an exact 8-bit integral type. The arithmetic could be handled using shifts and masks of wider registers to 'emulate' 8-bit arithmetic.

Comment: That would be true if you were coding in assembly. However, I don't believe that C supports types with a bitsize below a byte (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Compilers do this all the time - implementing 8-bit 'char' or 16-bit 'short' on 32-bit RISC with no native 8-bit byte (R/W) support.

Comment: Right. But registers exist with those exact sizes, whereas an 8-bit register would not exist on an architecture with 9-bit bytes. I don't know nearly enough about the C implementation to tell you you're wrong, but I swear I've read documentation somewhere that C will not support types below a byte in size. I'm happy to be proven wrong though.

Comment: C has bitfields; `int x:3;` is 3 bits on every machine. And thus there's also an eight bit variable available, even though it wouldn't match the native size of anything.