# A byte has 8-bits. Can it be larger in another system? give an example

Tags: masm

A byte has 8-bits. Can it be larger in another system? Give an example.

Also, how many different types of calls such as writeint,writedec,writestring,writechar are there in assembly language.
Thanks.

Comment: Part 1 of the question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit

Comment: For part 2, since you tagged this masm, seems to be a question you can answer yourself researching the masm documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afzk3475.aspx

Comment: @Penpa Gyaltsen if the answer given below satisfies you, consider accepting it, marking the symbol on the left. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not any more. There was a time, yes, when there were systems without a fundamental 8-bit byte.

- [System where 1 byte != 8 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit)

> how many different types of call such as writeint,writedec,writestring,writechar are there in assembly language

This question makes no sense. Assembly language is just a means of writing code that translates directly to machine instructions. `call` is just one of these instructions - it jumps to some other section of code, with the intent of returning to the place where the call was made.

The things you're referring to sound more like library routines - in which case there are any number of them, depending on the programming environment.