# Reading 16-bit integers from binary file c++

Tags: c++, binary, sizeof

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right so I want to check my code. it works but I'm not sure its working right. I need it to read the binary file, and store the 16 bit integers in an array of ints that is the exact size needed. I tried to do `sizeof(storage[i])` so I could see if I was storing 16 bits but it says 32 (I'm guessing because int automatically allocates 4 bytes?

```
        void q1run(question q){
        int end;
        std::string input = q.programInput;
        std::ifstream inputFile (input.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);                     //Open File
        if(inputFile.good()){                                       //Make sure file is open before trying to work with it
                                                                    //Begin Working with information
           cout << "In File:  \t" << input << endl;
           inputFile.seekg(0,ios::end);
           end=inputFile.tellg();
           int numberOfInts=end/2;
           int storage[numberOfInts];
           inputFile.clear();
           inputFile.seekg(0);
           int test = 0;


           while(inputFile.tellg()!=end){       
               inputFile.read((char*)&storage[test], sizeof(2));
               cout << "Currently at position" << inputFile.tellg() << endl;
               test++;
           }

           for(int i=0;i<numberOfInts;i++){
               cout << storage[i] << endl;
           }
       }else{
           cout << "Could not open file!!!" << endl;
      }
 }
```

EDIT:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;

I changed the read statement to:

```
      inputFile.read((char*)&storage[test], sizeof(2));
```

and the array to type `short`. now Its pretty well working except the output is a little strange:

```
      In File:        data02b.bin
      8
      Currently at position4
      Currently at position8
      10000
      10002
      10003
      0
```

I'm not sure what's in the .bin file, but I'm guessing the 0 shouldn't be there. lol

Comment: Storage is declared as an 'array' of "int"s, `sizeof(int)=4`

Comment: @AlecTeal Actually, that's architecture dependent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, int is 4 bytes (on 32-bit x86 platform).

You have two problems:

1. As Alec Teal correctly mentioned in comment, you have your storage declared as int, which means 4 bytes. Not a problem, really - your data will fit.
2. Actual problem: your line which is reading the file: `inputFile.read((char*)&storage[test], sizeof(2));` is actually reading 4 bytes, because 2 is integer, so `sizeof(2)` is 4. You don't need `sizeof` there.

Comment: While ScarletAmaranth's comment was technically right it's annoyingly pedantic, we're fine assuming a "normal" arch right? I've not seen one for example where a word isn't a multiple of 8 bits.

Comment: BTW upvote for spotting `sizeof(2)` - I completely ignored that - as did everyone else!

Comment: @AlecTeal: thanks. It's the main problem anyways - storing shorts as ints is perfectly fine, the problem is that the file reading is messed up.

Comment: Exactly, I mentioned that because new programmers tend to focus on memory more than they need to (or indeed ought to), too often I see people turning off RTTI or forcing GCC to not pack stuff for cache-hits, awful :P

Comment: I got it figured out based on this, had to use sizeof(1) or sizeof(short). thanks!

Comment: @DarkWanderer wtf at `sizeof(1)` - if you ever find out, tell me!

Comment: @AlecTeal: What does "word isn't multiple of 8 bits" have to do with assuming that `sizeof(int)` == 4, or that `sizeof(short)` == 2?  There are (I won't say plenty, but several) common architectures where `sizeof(int)` is not 4, even if `CHARBIT` is 8.  I'm all for making assumptions when it is inconvenient to do otherwise, but in this case, we have `int16_t`, which is convenient, and makes the intent of the code more clear.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley totally, but the word pedant exists, the point of my comment was "has anyone ever actually seen a case where it's not a multiple of 8 bits to the word." - don't worry about it, the question is solved now.

Answer (score 9):

Use: `int16_t` in `<cstdint>`. (guaranteed 16bits)

`Short`s and `int`s can be of various sizes depending on the architecture.

Comment: Nitpick - guaranteed 16 bits, but not two bytes.

Comment: @Nitpick explain please?

Answer (score 0):

Storage is declared as an 'array' of "int"s, sizeof(int)=4

This shouldn't be a problem though, you can fit 16 bit values in 32 bit spaces, you probably meant `short storage[...`

Additionally for the sake of full-disclosure, sizes are defined in terms of sizeof(char) as a monotonically increasing sequence.

4 is by far the most common though, hence the assumption. (Limits.h will clarify)

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1. I don't see how you can define sizes of other types *in terms of sizeof(char)*.

Comment: @Praetorian well done? Anyway a a char is a number of 0s and 1s or "bits", and there's no reason a char must be a multiple of 8 bytes (usually just 8) it could be 7! limits.h defines these limits so you can create portable code.

Comment: No, actually a `char` [must be at least 8 bits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5516161/241631). I'm aware of *limits.h* and how to write portable code, since I've worked a lot on a TI DSP with 16-bit chars. But your response fails to address my original question, which was how sizes of other types can be *defined in terms of sizeof(char)* as you claim in your answer. Also, I don't see the need for the sarcasm in your reply.

Answer (score 0):

One way to store 16 bits integers is to use the type `short` or `unsigned short`.

You used `sizeof(2)` which is equal to 4 because 2 is of type `int` so the the way to read 16 is to make `storage` of type `short` and the read:

```
short storage[numberOfInts];
....    
inputFile.read((char*)&storage[test], sizeof(short));
```

You can find [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) a table containing the sizes of all the types.

Comment: Thank you, I gave the check to the comment above me for saying almost the same thing, but very helpful nonetheless