# Random numbers from Char Array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, random

I'm trying to get randomly a number from an array, so, I did it like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
const char numbers[19] ={506001, 506002, 506003, 506004, 506005, 506006, 506007, 506008, 506009, 506010, 506011, 506012, 506013, 506014, 506015, 506016, 506017, 506018, 506019};
printf("%i",(int)numbers[rand() % 19]);
printf("\n");
```

But instead of giving me a number from the array it prints any other value in negative.
[image: Output]

Also, With numbers that are short than 3 digits it works fine, the problem starts when I use 3 or more digits numbers.
What am I doing bad?

Comment: `char` is one byte. Are you using one of those 32-bit byte systems? By the way, `char` already gets converted to `int` when going into an ellipsis (like `printf`'s).

Comment: The screenshot is a large chunk of no information. Consider removing it. While you are at it, decide which language you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
const char numbers[19] ...
```

to

```
const long numbers[19] ...
```

A char is 1 byte ([8 bits at least for most modern machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit)). Your numbers are too large for a char.
The size of the long (it looks like you have a Windows system) is at least 32 bits.

Comment: A `char` does not have to be 8 bits. It does have to be one byte.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `const char numbers[19]`, ie.
19 const (signed) `char`'s.
A `signed char` can only hold values from `-128` to `+127`, any other numbers are not possible.
Use `const int numbers[19]`.

Comment: `char` can be signed or unsigned and can sometimes store a higher range than that.

Comment: In his case, it´s clearly signed, but thanks for remembering me of the range thing. I got too used to "normal" machines...

Comment: @deviantfan There are also not "normal" machines that have a `INT_MAX` of 32767.  Common in the embedded world of 2013.  Better to use `long` for values like 506001 to 506019.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting integers into a character array.  You probably want:

```
const long numbers[19] ={506001, 506002, 506003, 506004, 506005, 506006, 506007, 506008, 506009, 506010, 506011, 506012, 506013, 506014, 506015, 506016, 506017, 506018, 506019};
```