# What determines an architectures byte size?

Tags: byte, ram, cpu-architecture

Am I correct in saying that if I construct a RAM of `x` storage locations, each of which is `y`-bits wide, then I have `xy`bits of `y`-bit RAM?

Questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit?rq=1) explain with historical examples why we cannot rely on `8b == 1B`, but I cannot find confirmation of what this means in terms of architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly older, and slightly wiser, I think I can answer my own question.

Given an `N`-bit address bus, there are `2^N` addressable memory locations.

If an `M`-bit data bus is desired, then `log M` bits address columns, and `N - log M` address rows into the RAM.

So back to the question; `N := x, M := y`, and we have `y*2^x` bits of `y`-bit RAM.

[image: Quick sketch of numerical example]

For numerical example, suppose a 12-bit address and 16-bit data. 8 bits address `2^8 =` 256 rows; the remaining 4 bits address 16x 16:1 multiplexers on the columns, giving 16 bits of data output. (As shown above).