# Iterate through bits in C

Tags: c, bit, bitarray

I have a big char *str where the first 8 chars (which equals 64 bits if I'm not wrong), represents a bitmap. Is there any way to iterate through these 8 chars and see which bits are 0? I'm having alot of trouble understanding the concept of bits, as you can't "see" them in the code, so I can't think of any way to do this.

Comment: Suggest showing sample "first 8 chars".  What do you mean by "first 8 chars" and then "these 4 chars"?

Comment: 4 was just a typo. When I say the first 8 chars I mean str[1,2,...,8]

Comment: Surely you mean 0...7 instead of 1...8 ? Because array indizes in C begin at 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Imagine you have only one byte, a single char `my_char`. You can test for individual bits using bitwise operators and bit shifts.

```
unsigned char my_char = 0xAA;
int what_bit_i_am_testing = 0;

while (what_bit_i_am_testing < 8) {
  if (my_char & 0x01) {
     printf("bit %d is 1\n", what_bit_i_am_testing);
  }
  else {
     printf("bit %d is 0\n", what_bit_i_am_testing);
  }

  what_bit_i_am_testing++;
  my_char = my_char >> 1;
}
```

The part that must be new to you, is the `>>` operator. This operator will "insert a zero on the left and push every bit to the right, and the rightmost will be thrown away".

That was not a very technical description for a right bit shift of 1.

Comment: Would be good to emphasize that `my_char` must be `unsigned` for this code to work correctly for all values (and not run forever for some values).

Comment: yes, you are correct. but since he said his context was a bitmap image, to be clear and concise i omitted all of those considerations. too much info might confuse a newcomer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why have you used my_char & 0x01?

Comment: this is the important part, its a bitmask. read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing) they put it well there

Comment: This is a destructive solution, if OP wants to read the bits of a bitmap, this is unsuitable.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Why is that unsuitable? my_char can just be a temp var... `my_char = my_bitmap[1234];`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to iterate over each of the set bits of an unsigned integer (use unsigned rather than signed integers for well-defined behaviour; unsigned of any width should be fine), one bit at a time.

Define the following macros:

```
#define LSBIT(X)                    ((X) & (-(X)))
#define CLEARLSBIT(X)               ((X) & ((X) - 1))
```

Then you can use the following idiom to iterate over the set bits, LSbit first:

```
unsigned temp_bits;
unsigned one_bit;

temp_bits = some_value;
for ( ; temp_bits; temp_bits = CLEARLSBIT(temp_bits) ) {
    one_bit = LSBIT(temp_bits);
    /* Do something with one_bit */
}
```

I'm not sure whether this suits your needs. You said you want to check for `0` bits, rather than `1` bits — maybe you could bitwise-invert the initial value. Also for multi-byte values, you could put it in another `for` loop to process one byte/word at a time.

Answer (score 3):

In the C language, chars are 8-bit wide bytes, and in general in computer science, data is organized around bytes as the fundamental unit.

In some cases, such as your problem, data is stored as boolean values in individual bits, so we need a way to determine whether a particular bit in a particular byte is on or off. There is already an SO solution for this explaining [how to do bit manipulations in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c).

To check a bit, the usual method is to AND it with the bit you want to check:

```
int isBitSet = bitmap & (1 << bit_position);
```

If the variable isBitSet is 0 after this operation, then the bit is not set. Any other value indicates that the bit is on.

Comment: `s/8-bit wide/at least 8-bit wide`

Comment: In the C language, chars are `CHAR_BIT` wide bytes.  `CHAR_BIT` is _at least_ 8.

Comment: @chux The only modern systems which have super-octet bytes are highly specialized embedded systems. There are no modern super-octet general computing architectures, so from a practical point of view a char is always 8-bits.

Comment: @Tyler Durden 1 ) This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit) digs into present day situation concerning the rare `CHAR_BIT != 8`.  2) As C does not require new systems to use `CHAR_BIT == 8`, future systems _may_ use super-octet `char`.

Comment: @Tyler Durden 3) Much like 2014 systems overwhelmingly use of 2's complement for `int` and so `int` overflow _should_ be well defined.  Since the C spec leaves `int` overflow as undefined to accommodate those old pesky obsolete sign-magnitude, 1’s complement, padded integers, smarter compilers have taken advantage of that and create code that breaks former code that relied on well-defined 2's complement overflow.  Why did coders count on well-defined 2's complement overflow – because “all” modern systems use 2’s complement.

Comment: @Tyler Durden 3b) In a likewise fashion, a savvy compiler may take advantage that `CHAR_BIT` may be greater than 8 for some future optimization.  Suggest using `(u)int8_t` if code needs an 8-bit integer.

Answer (score 3):

It's true for little-endian memory architecture:

```
const int cBitmapSize = 8;
const int cBitsCount = cBitmapSize * 8;
const unsigned char cBitmap[cBitmapSize] = /* some data */;

for(int n = 0; n < cBitsCount; n++)
{
  unsigned char Mask = 1 << (n % 8);
  if(cBitmap[n / 8] & Mask)
  {
    // if n'th bit is 1...
  }
}
```

Comment: And also for big-endian, so why mention it?  Endianness has only to do with the ordering of bytes inside larger units (shorts, integers, and larger). Bit order, quite fortunately, is the same for big, middle, and little-endian systems.

Answer (score 2):

For one char `b` you can simply iterate like this :

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
  printf("This is the %d-th bit : %d\n",i,(b>>i)&1);
}
```

You can then iterate through the chars as needed.

What you should understand is that you cannot manipulate directly the bits, you can just use some arithmetic properties of number in base 2 to compute numbers that in some way represents some bits you want to know.

How does it work for example ? In a char there is 8 bits. A char can be see as a number written with 8 bits in base 2. If the number in b is b7b6b5b4b3b2b1b0 (each being a digit) then b>>i is b shifted to the right by i positions (in the left 0's are pushed). So, 10110111 >> 2 is 00101101, then the operation &1 isolate the last bit (bitwise and operator).

Comment: OK, now that you've got it fixed, I suggest including `<limits.h>` and changing `8` to `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: By the way, if you have some `char b` equal the binary value of `10110111`, and you do `b >> 2`, what you get is `11101101`, not `00101101`. This is because `char` is `signed char` by default, and when performing right-shift on a `signed` variable, the sign-bit follows to the right. For `b >> 2` to yield `00101101`, you must declare `unsigned char b`.

Comment: I didn't want to be such pedantic. He needed only basic advices about bit manipulation.

Comment: Don't be cheap on pedanticism here, especially if it's only a few of more lines of information. OP (and other users reading this answer in the future) will just end up running into a different problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through all char.

```
char *str = "MNO"; // M=01001101, N=01001110, O=01001111
int bit = 0;

for (int x = strlen(str)-1; x > -1; x--){ // Start from O, N, M
    
    printf("Char %c \n", str[x]);
 
    for(int y=0; y<8; y++){ // Iterate though every bit
    // Shift bit the the right with y step and mask last position
        if( str[x]>>y & 0b00000001 ){ 
            printf("bit %d = 1\n", bit);
        }else{
            printf("bit %d = 0\n", bit);
        }
        bit++;
    }
    
}
```

output

```
Char O
bit 0 = 1
bit 1 = 1
bit 2 = 1
bit 3 = 1
bit 4 = 0
bit 5 = 0
bit 6 = 1
bit 7 = 0
Char N 
bit 8 = 0
bit 9 = 1
bit 10 = 1
...
```