# Why does wmemcpy exist when memcpy should suffice?

Tags: c, memcpy

`wmemcpy` appears to perform the same operations as `memcpy` but accepts `wchar_t*` instead of `void*`. How is its existence justified if these two code snippets should have the same behaviour? Does it have a useful purpose?

```
memcpy(dest, wchar_array, sizeof(wchar_array));
```

And

```
wmemcpy(dest, wchar_array, sizeof(wchar_array) / sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Comment: because human beings like to create stuff... not necessarily good stuff... But for some, just building a huge junk collection gives them self worth.

Comment: A weak reason may be that when you have an array of `wchar_t`, `wmemcpy` may be more efficient because it can assume suitable alignment.

Comment: @Lashlane `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(wchar_t));` prints 4 in my Debian virtual machine.

Comment: @jdarthenay yep, size of wchar is implementation defined, msvc uses 2 bytes though

Comment: @Lashane: The term "Word" is not synonym for "2 bytes". As is "1 byte" not 8 bits.

Comment: @Olaf I know this, but 99% of the time - word is 2/4 bytes, and byte is 8 bits. Its much easier to live in real world without nitpicking every word.

Comment: @Lashane: There is little use in using wrong terms without need. The word "octet" is only one letter more to type. And stating "word == 2 bytes" was just a bad idea (you apparently noticed yourself). "I know this" - Problem is this is read by beginners mostly who take such statements as universally valid. Just see the questions here with errors resulting from users making wrong assumptions about sizes.

Comment: @JordanMelo I'd never heard of wmemcpy until you asked about it just now.  I agree that its existence seems unjustified.  Me, I'd never use it.

Comment: @Olaf You're fighting a losing battle on "byte".  It's a word with multiple meanings (just like "hacker").  For at least 99% of speakers, in common usage, "byte" means "8 bits".

Comment: @SteveSummit can you point to a single counter-example where "byte" means anything other than 8 bits? I don't think the uncommon CPUs that use non-8-bit smallest addressable units use the term "byte" for that.

Comment: @Olaf the "W" in this case stands for *wide*, not *word*.

Comment: @MarkRansom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit

Comment: @MarkRansom: The original comment was deleted, you missed context.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Yes, that's because people who should know better invoking the impressing "byte <=> 8 bits". And now you tell me correcting this is wrong, because - what? Call me old fashioned, but I honestly think using precise terminology is vital in engineering at least (and could help in other fields, too. I'm apparently lucky my customers seem to appreciate my pedantry.

Comment: @Lashane I know there are lots of CPUs where a *char* isn't 8 bits, but I don't recall the term *byte* being used in that context. My opinion is that references to "byte" in that answer are misrepresentations.

Comment: @MarkRansom I have it on good authority that, once upon a time, there were indeed machines with 7- and 9-bit bytes. But my point was that, today, making the assumption that bytes are 8 bits is so popular that (to a descriptivist like me) it's accurate, per common usage, no matter how much the pedants rail against it.

Comment: @MarkRansom one of the anwers states `The size of a byte was at first selected to be a multiple of existing teletypewriter codes, particularly the 6-bit codes used by the U.S. Army (Fieldata) and Navy. `

Comment: @MarkRansom: See the C standard. The terms "byte" and `char` are used as synonyms. There is a reason the network standards use "octets".

Comment: @Lashane: IIRC, TTYs used a 5 bit code with shift-codes (which is one reason older UARTs allowed for symbol data length of 5..n bits). But that was before my time, so it is just hearsay.

Comment: @Lashane again, my argument isn't about the size of a character, or the size of the smallest addressable unit, it's about the definition of the word "byte". I don't think the term was historically used to refer to any quantity other than 8 bits.

Comment: @MarkRansom IBM 7030 Stretch had variable length bytes, so byte was 1-8 bits

Comment: @Lashane your comment led me to [COMPUTER USAGE COMMINUQUÉ Vol. 2 No. 3](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Computer_Usage_Company/cuc.communique_vol2no3.1963.102651922.pdf) from 1963 which indeed uses the term "byte" in the context you describe. I'll shut up now. Thank you very much for the concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to  davmac's answer about API symmetry and having the size of an array not always granted, it should be emphasized that the third argument of `wmemcpy` refers to number of elements to copy (rather than bytes).

If you work with `wchar_t` objects and handle them with other functions from `<wchar.h>`, it may facilitate matters. `wcslen` for instance returns the C wide string length in terms of `wchar_t` elements, and `wcschr` and `wcsrchr` return `wchar_t *`, thus using them to do some pointer arithmetic also keeps you in the "realm" of number-of-elements.

P.S. If the size of the minimal `wchar_t` array is given as implied in your example, using `wmemcpy` may result in more elegant code than that `sizeof(wchar_array)` you used:

```
#define SIZE 40
wchar_t wchar_array[SIZE];
// ...
wmemcpy(dest, wchar_array, SIZE);
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's largely about API symmetry, but also, it allows more easily writing code which can work with both wide character and normal strings (switched over by a preprocessor define or similar).

Essentially, if you want your code to work with `char`, you `#define` your copy function as `memcpy`. For `wchar_t`, you define it as `wmemcpy` instead. Your size argument is just the number of characters (either `char` or `wchar_t`); remember that the argument isn't necessarily a fixed size array, so using `sizeof` isn't always an option.

The Win32 API for instance makes use of a similar strategy: If you define the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol, most functions resolve to their wide-character version (suffixed with W) but otherwise they resolve to the "narrow" character version (suffixed with A); `TCHAR` is defined as either `char` or `wchar_t` accordingly; etc. The upshot is you can write code which works with either wide or regular characters fairly easily.

Of course, this is in no way *necessary*; but then, the standard C library isn't necessarily supposed to be absolutely minimal. You could argue that `calloc` is superfluous since you can always use `malloc` and then `memset`, for instance; it still exists, however.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense, because I often need to `memcpy` things like integers or floats. Why not have a `imemcpy()` or `fmemcpy()`? Why does `wchar_t` get its own function? `memcpy` works on the basis that `char` is a single byte, not that it's a character; `wchar_t` doesn't have that special property, though.

Comment: @Cornstalks but ints and floats aren't (generally) used to hold characters. `chart` and `wchar_t` both are; the difference bewteen them is mainly their width/range. Because of this, it makes sense that you might want to write code that works with either (or at least, which is switchable to support either).

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that I don't think `memcpy` is geared towards characters/strings. If it was, I'd expect it to take a `char*` instead of a `void*`.

Comment: @Cornstalks it's not _geared_ towards strings, but you can still use it copy strings; you can pass it a `char *` without issue. I'm not suggesting this should generally be done, but it can be done, and probably has been done.

Comment: I could easily `#define` my copy function to something like `#define copy(dest,src,size) memcpy(dest,src,(size)*2) ` instead of `wmemcpy(dest,src,size)` for `wchar_t` and get the same effect. It's a fairly trivial transformation. But that's a good point for why someone might have wanted it.

Comment: @JordanMelo sure, you could. I don't think the existence of `wmemcpy` is really necessary; it mainly just rounds out the w* functions so that most of the regular mem* functions have wide-character equivalents. But it's certainly not causing a problem by existing. :)