# Restrict size of int data type

Tags: c++, c, c++11

How to restrict size of int data type to 4 bytes in 32 and 64 bits machine irrespective of the compiler type?
Do I have to use stdint.h?

Comment: Choose *one* language.  C and C++ are not the same thing.

Comment: Here on SO we expect a bit of degree and _research_ before asking.

Comment: See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) or [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: Do you mean `int` or, more generally, integer types? They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

In general, you can't, unless you write your own compiler.

The size of `int` is implementation-defined, which means that each compiler determines its size.

It's *usually* 4 bytes / 32 bits, but that's not guaranteed. (Bytes aren't even guaranteed to be exactly 8 bits but you're unlikely to run into a system where they aren't.)

What you can do is ensure that your code will fail to compile if the compiler uses a size you don't like:

```
#include <limits.h>

#if INT_MAX != 0x7FFFFFFF
#error "This code requires 32-bit int"
#endif
```

Since you asked about `int`, that's the answer. If you really meant that you want a 32-bit *integer* type, then you can use the type `int32_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`, or `uint32_t` if you need an unsigned type. Implementations that don't have any 32-bit integer type, or whose 32-bit types don't meet certain requirements, will not define `int32_t` and `uint32_t` -- but again, you're not likely to run into such a system.

Keep in mind that `int` doesn't just mean "integer"; the type `int` is one of several integer types.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I just mentioned that in my edit a few seconds ago. But the question asked about `int`, not about integer types in general.

Comment: Also notice `int32_t` can be 32 bits but not 4 bytes. And it may not also be available at all - there you want to fail fast. Run as far as possible.

Comment: @black Isn't 4 bytes == 32 bits?

Comment: @mikeyq6 Realistically, yes. [But could also be different.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot force a compiler to change how many bits it uses for an `int`. If your need is to capture integral data using a 32-bit integral type, use `int32_t`.

Answer (score 2):

You have no control over how the compiler manages its native data types.  But you can chose how you decide to use them.  For instance, when compiling for 32bit, use `int32_t` (always 32bit).  When compiling for 64bit, use `int64_t` (always 64bit).  If you need to use a single type that can size itself depending on whether you are compiling for 32bit or 64bit, use `intptr_t` (always 32bit or 64bit, respectively).  So yes, you should be using the types defined in `stdint.h` if the number of bits in an integer type matters to you.