# What is the most suitable type of vector to keep the bytes of a file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, byte, bit

What is the most suitable type of vector to keep the bytes of a file?

I'm considering using the int type, because the bits "00000000" (1 byte) are interpreted to 0!

The goal is to save this data (bytes) to a file and retrieve from this file later.

NOTE: The files contain null bytes ("00000000" in bits)!

I'm a bit lost here. Help me! =D Thanks!

---

**UPDATE I:**

To read the file I'm using this function:

```
char* readFileBytes(const char *name){
    std::ifstream fl(name);
    fl.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
    size_t len = fl.tellg();
    char *ret = new char[len];
    fl.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    fl.read(ret, len);
    fl.close();
    return ret;
}
```

**NOTE I:** I need to find a way to ensure that bits "00000000" can be recovered from the file!

**NOTE II:** Any suggestions for a safe way to save those bits "00000000" to a file?

**NOTE III:** When using char array I had problems converting bits "00000000" for that type.

Code Snippet:

```
int bit8Array[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
char charByte = (bit8Array[7]     ) | 
                (bit8Array[6] << 1) | 
                (bit8Array[5] << 2) | 
                (bit8Array[4] << 3) | 
                (bit8Array[3] << 4) | 
                (bit8Array[2] << 5) | 
                (bit8Array[1] << 6) | 
                (bit8Array[0] << 7);
```

---

**UPDATE II:**

Following the @chqrlie recommendations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<unsigned char> readFileBytes(const char* filename)
{
    // Open the file.
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);

    // Stop eating new lines in binary mode!
    file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    // Get its size
    std::streampos fileSize;

    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // Reserve capacity.
    std::vector<unsigned char> unsignedCharVec;
    unsignedCharVec.reserve(fileSize);

    // Read the data.
    unsignedCharVec.insert(unsignedCharVec.begin(),
               std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(file),
               std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>());

    return unsignedCharVec;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<unsigned char> unsignedCharVec;

    // txt file contents "xz"
    unsignedCharVec=readFileBytes("xz.txt");

    // Letters -> UTF8/HEX -> bits!
    // x -> 78 -> 0111 1000
    // z -> 7a -> 0111 1010

    for(unsigned char c : unsignedCharVec){
        printf("%c\n", c);
        for(int o=7; o >= 0; o--){
            printf("%i", ((c >> o) & 1));
        }
        printf("%s", "\n");
    }

    // Prints...
    // x
    // 01111000
    // z
    // 01111010

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE III:**

This is the code I am using using to write to a binary file:

```
void writeFileBytes(const char* filename, std::vector<unsigned char>& fileBytes){
    std::ofstream file(filename, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
    file.write(fileBytes.size() ? (char*)&fileBytes[0] : 0, 
               std::streamsize(fileBytes.size()));
}

writeFileBytes("xz.bin", fileBytesOutput);
```

---

**UPDATE IV:**

Futher read about **UPDATE III**:

[c++ - Save the contents of a "std::vector<unsigned char>" to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052857/c-save-the-contents-of-a-stdvectorunsigned-char-to-a-file)

---

**CONCLUSION:**

Definitely the solution to the problem of the "00000000" bits (1 byte) was change the type that stores the bytes of the file to `std::vector<unsigned char>` as the guidance of friends. `std::vector<unsigned char>` is a universal type (exists in all environments) and will accept any octal (unlike char* in "UPDATE I")!

In addition, changing from array (char) to vector (unsigned char) was crucial for success! With vector I manipulate my data more securely and completely independent of its content (in char array I have problems with this).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you doing with those bytes?

Comment: `unsigned char` will hold generic bytes.

Comment: I'd use `uint8_t`

Comment: @NathanOliver Save to a file and read this file later. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with krzaq - use `uint8_t`.

Comment: @krzaq: Why would one prefer uint8_t over unsigned char for reading bytes? Legitimately curious.

Comment: Just remember that when you use `uint8_t` you normally have a `unsigned char`  as it is just a typedef.  It can cause some fun output issues.

Comment: @AndyG you make a good point. I guess I would want the compiler to warn me if I'm dealing with a non-standard sized byte, but that can be achieved with `static_assert`. And `unsinged char` is more likely to be of size of the underlying byte, so... Maybe my gut feeling isn't correct here, I'll have to think this over.

Comment: @krzaq how you expect compiler to warn you about non standard sized byte?

Comment: @Slava I assume I'd get warning about a narrowing conversion from `BYTE*` to `smaller_than_byte*`. Then again, I guess you can't have a type smaller than the underlying byte... As I said, usually I use sized types first, question them later, so I may not be correct here.

Comment: you cannot have data type smaller than `char` aka `byte` in C++ period. So what narrowinng you are talking about?

Comment: None, I guess. But in that case I'd either get a compile error (`uint8_t` unavailable) or it'd be big enough to keep a byte of information.

Comment: Why don't you mmap the file instead of reading it?

Comment: The file reading and writing functions are going to be fine with null characters, as will the standard containers - including even `std::string`! I'm not sure what your problem is. Maybe you're not opening the file in binary mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 problems in your code:

- You use the `char` type and return a `char *`.  Yet the return value is not a proper C string as you do not allocate an extra byte for the `'\0'` terminator nor null terminate it.
- If the file may contain null bytes, you should probably use type `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` to make it explicit that the array does not contain text.
- You do not return the array size to the caller. The caller has no way to tell how long the array is.  You should probably use a `std::vector<uint8_t>` or `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of an array allocated with `new`.

Comment: I followed your recommendations. Seems to me that "unsigned char" is the solution to my "00000000" bits (byte). I'll do the tests. I'll give you a return! Thanks! =D

Comment: @EduardoLucio point 3 is the important one here. You need a way to tell how long the data is, otherwise the convention is to mark the end with a value of 0 bits. I'm assuming that's the source of your problems. Otherwise it shouldn't matter whether you're using `char`, `unsigned char`, or `uint8_t`, except for documenting what you're doing - they'll all behave the same. Keeping bytes in a `char` array is such a common thing that nobody will be confused by it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::vector<unsigned char>`. Don't use `std::uint8_t`: it's won't exist on systems that don't have a native hardware type of exactly 8 bits. `unsigned char` will always exist; it will usually be the smallest addressable type that the hardware supports, and it's required to be at least 8 bits wide, so if you're trafficking in 8-bit bytes, it will handle the bits that you need.

If you really, really, really like the fixed-width types, you might consider `std::uint_least8_t`, which will always exist, and has at least eight bits, or `std::uint_fast8_t`, which also has at least eight bits. But file I/O traffics in `char` types, and mixing `char` and it's variants with vaguely specified "least" and "fast" types may well get confusing.

Comment: Seems to me that "unsigned char" is the solution to my "00000000" bits (byte). I'll do the tests. I'll give a return! Thanks! =D

Answer (score 1):

`uint8_t` is the winner in my eyes:

- it's exactly 8 bits, or 1 byte, long;
- it's unsigned without requiring you to type `unsigned` every time;
- it's exactly the same on all platforms;
- it's a generic type that does not imply any specific use, unlike `char` / `unsigned char`, which is associated with characters of text even if it can technically be used for any purpose just the same as `uint8_t`.

Bottom line: `uint8_t` is functionally equivalent to `unsigned char`, but does a better job of saying *this is some data of unspecified nature* in the source code.

So use `std::vector<uint8_t>`.
`#include <stdint.h>` to make the `uint8_t` definition available.

P. S. As pointed out in the comments, the C++ standard defines `char` as 1 byte, and byte is not, strictly speaking, required to be the same as `octet` (8 bits). On such a hypothetical system,  `char` will still exist and will be 1 byte long, but `uint8_t` is defined as 8 bits (`octet`) and thus may not exist (due to implementation difficulties / overhead). So `char` is more portable, theoretically speaking, but `uint8_t` is more strict and has wider guarantees of expected behavior.

Comment: What if I have a frankenstein OS where 1 byte is not 8 bits?

Comment: *regardless of char width* Um, the width of `char` is **always** 1

Comment: @NathanOliver: is it really? Okay, I'll remove that line, but `char` is still not as explicit.

Comment: In C++ definition 1 byte is equal to 1 char, not 8 bits.

Comment: If the OS does not 8-bit bytes, what makes you think the input data does?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yep.  `sizeof(char) == sizeof(signed char) == sizeof(unsigned char) == 1`.

Comment: `error: unrecognised identifier \`sizeod' on line 1`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Recompile

Comment: @NathanOliver: thank you sir it works now. i have another question do you know how to make music in c++

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `std::cout << "\a";` will start you on your way,  You just need to add some pauses between the "notes"

Comment: I am afraid on a system, where 1 char has more than 8 bits, `uint8_t` either will not be supported or would have more than 8 bits as well, as data type cannot have `sizeof` < 1

Comment: @Slava It won't exist as `uint8_t` is required to only be 8 bits wide.  The implementation can only provide the type if there is a corresponding basic type of the right size.

Comment: @NathanOliver: will `char` exist on such a system?

Comment: @NathanOliver then `unsigned char` is more portable than `uint8_t`

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yep.  And it's size will be 1.

Comment: @NathanOliver: 1 what? :) Platform-defined byte?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Yes. A byte's size is _already_ platform-defined. Don't confuse "byte" for "octet".

Comment: @VioletGiraffe yes `sizeof(char)==1` that is written in standard. And `byte` in C++ is a `char`. So some recommend call 8 bits `octet` rather than byte.

Comment: @Slava: are there any non-extinct systems where byte does not consist of 8 bits?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Fun read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char

Comment: @VioletGiraffe another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit

Comment: Standard says: `typedef unsigned integer type uint8_t; // optional`, so `it's exactly the same on all platform` is inaccurate.

Comment: @kfsone: Exactly the same as long as it exists, no? And if it doesn't exist, there's probably a good reason, so the compilation will _fail-fast_ instead of silently compiling the code that may not do what you expect.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Fun indeed. All the more reason to use fixed-width types, if you ask me.