# Convert array values of 1's and 0's to binary

Tags: c++, arduino

In Arduino IDE, I am placing all of input values to an array like so:

```
int eOb1 = digitalRead(PrOb1);
int eLoop = digitalRead(PrLoop);
int eOb2 = digitalRead(PrOb2);

InputValues[0] = eOb1;
InputValues[1] = eLoop;
InputValues[2] = eOb2;
InputValues[3] = 0;
InputValues[4] = 0;
InputValues[5] = 0;
InputValues[6] = 0;
InputValues[7] = 0;
```

I would like to convert it to a byte array like so: `00000111`.
Can you show me please. I tried using a for Loop to iterate through the values but it doesn't work.

```
char bin[8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
   bin &= InputValues[i];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by byte array? I got confused when I started to answer. You want to get a byte having bits set as per `InputValues`?

Comment: I want to Serial.println the result as "0000111". The InputValues[0] to InputValues[2] can be 1 or 0 depending on the toggled switch.

Comment: Please see my updated code that incorporated your previous suggestion.

Comment: Initialise `char bin = 0;`

Comment: Just "0000111". One string only just like a byte value.

Comment: @stackquestions please do not change the question to incorporate a presented solution. It leaves the questions and answers in an inconsistent state. I am rolling back your edit for this one.

Comment: @stackquestions your last comment is very confusing. Do you want a string or a byte value. They are not *like* each other at all.

Comment: Am sorry for the confusion. I just want it to be one string of "0000101". Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you have an array of individual bits and you need to convert it into a byte that has the corresponding bits.

So to start, you should declare `bin` to be of type `unsigned char` instead of `char[8]`. `char[8]` means an array of 8 bytes, whereas you only need a single byte.

Then you need to initialize it to 0. (This is important since `|=` needs the variable to have some defined value).

```
unsigned char bin;
```

Now, `unsigned char` is guaranteed to have 1 byte but not 8 bits. So you should use something like `uint8_t` IF it is available.

Finally you can set the appropriate bits in `bin` as -

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bin |= (InputValues[i] << i);
}
```

There are two things I have changed.

1. I used `|=` instead of `&=`. This is the bitwise OR operator. You need to use OR because it only sets the correct bits in the LHS and leaves other bits untouched. An AND won't necessarily set that bit and will also mask away (set to 0), the other bits.
2. Shifted the bit in the array to the corresponding position using `<< i`.

Comment: It worked! But it is giving me 1 or 2 or 7 or 3. It's giving out hex. Can I have it as byte only like "0000101"?

Comment: `uint8_t` is always available in standard C, unless someone gets the not-too-brilliant idea to write code for various obsolete, oddball TI DSPs in C.

Comment: “have 1 byte but not 8 bits.” really?? Can you show me an example that unsigned char is 1 byte ,but not 8 bits?

Comment: @peter__barnes take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit)