# Segmentation fault, on the border ranges of int

Tags: c, malloc

**Create a function ft_range which returns an array ofints. This int array should contain all values between min and max.
Min included - max excluded.**

```
#include <printf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int *ft_range(int min, int max)
{
    int *ptrInt;
    int i;
    int temp;
    temp = min;
    i = 0;
    ptrInt = NULL;
    if (max < min)
    {
        return (ptrInt);
    } else
    {
        ptrInt = malloc(max - min);
    }
    while (i < (max - min))
    {
        *(ptrInt + i) = temp + i;
        i++; /trows segfault at i == 473742332
    }
    return (ptrInt);
}



int *ft_range(int min, int max);

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int min = -947483640;
    int max =  947483640;
    int *ptr = ft_range(min, max);

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", *ptr);
        printf("%c", '\n');
    }
}
```

If i put bigger values, segfault throws also on the bigger values.
And this code works perfectly on the lower values.

Comment: `ptrInt = malloc(max - min);  **-->>** ptrInt = malloc((max - min) *sizeof *ptrInt);` Also,most people prefer array-notation: `*(ptrInt + i) = temp + i;` **-->>** `ptrInt[i] = temp + i;`

Comment: You're getting a segfault because you're invoking undefined behavior by writing past the size of the memory region that you've `malloc`ed. `malloc` accepts the number of bytes to allocate. `sizeof int` on your machine is surely larger than one byte, so simply allocating `max - min` bytes is not enough to store that many `int`s. After you fix your segfault, you're going to enter an infinite loop in `main`. `ptr` is never updated in your `while` loop.

Comment: If this is two separate source files, please indicate that. If not, normally all the `#include` directives go at the top of the file.

Comment: @wildplasser thank you, it helped.

Comment: There is also the corner case `min==max` , which is not caught by your check, but resulting in `malloc(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code allocates insufficient memory when `int` is wider than `char` - something that is very common.

Allocate based on the size of the pointed to object.  [@wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525504/segmetation-fault-on-the-border-ranges-of-int/52525713#comment91990837_52525504)

```
int *ptrInt;
...
  // ptrInt = malloc(max - min);
  ptrInt = malloc(sizeof *ptrInt * (max - min));
  //              ^------------^   ^---------^ number of elements
  //              +------------+-------------- size of 1 element
```

Comment: Is there a scenario where standard-conformant C does not have `int` wider than `char`?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Some graphics processors have been known to use the same 64-bit size for all integer types.  Unusual, but allowed by C.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have time to go over the standard at the moment, but isn't a `char` guaranteed to be one byte (that is, such that byte is defined by `CHAR_BIT` or some-such), and an `int` guaranteed no less than two bytes?

Comment: In C, a "byte" is at _least_ 8 bits.  Research `CHAR_BIT`.  A `char` uses `CHAR_BIT` bits - one C "byte".  If `CHAR_BIT >= 16` then an `int` could also be 1 C "byte".

Comment: Alright, I'll take your word on that for now.  I'll look it up in the standard later, but I trust that to be accurate.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons [System where 1 byte != 8 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5516161/2410359) may be useful.