# 16bit unsigned int array outputting more elements than initialized size in c

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, sizeof, conversion-specifier

I'm trying to feed data into an array and change only a few values and leaving the rest 0, but I keep receiving much more data than the array should theoretically hold. Here is my code compiled and run with

> gcc -o arr arrayconst.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(){    
    uint16_t buf_tx[101];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf_tx);i++){buf_tx[i]=0;}
    //memset(buf_tx,0,sizeof(buf_tx)*sizeof(uint16_t)); //alternate way of zeroizing
    buf_tx[42] = 0x2000;
    buf_tx[46] = 0x2000;
    buf_tx[48] = 0x2000;
    buf_tx[50] = 0x2000;
    buf_tx[52] = 0x2000;
    buf_tx[54] = 0x2000;
    buf_tx[72] = 0x1000;
    buf_tx[76] = 0x0001;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf_tx); i++){
        printf("|%d 0x%04X, ",i,buf_tx[i]);
        
    }
}
```

and my output:

> |0 0x0000, |1 0x0000, |2 0x0000, |3 0x0000, |4 0x0000, |5 0x0000, |6
> 0x0000, |7 0x0000, |8 0x0000, |9 0x0000, |10 0x0000, |11 0x0000, |12
> 0x0000, |13 0x0000, |14 0x0000, |15 0x0000, |16 0x0000, |17 0x0000,
> |18 0x0000, |19 0x0000, |20 0x0000, |21 0x0000, |22 0x0000, |23
> 0x0000, |24 0x0000, |25 0x0000, |26 0x0000, |27 0x0000, |28 0x0000,
> |29 0x0000, |30 0x0000, |31 0x0000, |32 0x0000, |33 0x0000, |34
> 0x0000, |35 0x0000, |36 0x0000, |37 0x0000, |38 0x0000, |39 0x0000,
> |40 0x0000, |41 0x0000, |42 0x2000, |43 0x0000, |44 0x0000, |45
> 0x0000, |46 0x2000, |47 0x0000, |48 0x2000, |49 0x0000, |50 0x2000,
> |51 0x0000, |52 0x2000, |53 0x0000, |54 0x2000, |55 0x0000, |56
> 0x0000, |57 0x0000, |58 0x0000, |59 0x0000, |60 0x0000, |61 0x0000,
> |62 0x0000, |63 0x0000, |64 0x0000, |65 0x0000, |66 0x0000, |67
> 0x0000, |68 0x0000, |69 0x0000, |70 0x0000, |71 0x0000, |72 0x1000,
> |73 0x0000, |74 0x0000, |75 0x0000, |76 0x0001, |77 0x0000, |78
> 0x0000, |79 0x0000, |80 0x0000, |81 0x0000, |82 0x0000, |83 0x0000,
> |84 0x0000, |85 0x0000, |86 0x0000, |87 0x0000, |88 0x0000, |89
> 0x0000, |90 0x0000, |91 0x0000, |92 0x0000, |93 0x0000, |94 0x0000,
> |95 0x0000, |96 0x0000, |97 0x0000, |98 0x0000, |99 0x0000, |100
> 0x0000, |101 0x0000, |102 0x0000, |103 0x0000, |104 0x0000, |105
> 0x0000, |106 0x0000, |107 0x0000, |108 0x0000, |109 0x0000, |110
> 0x0000, |111 0x0000, |112 0x0000, |113 0x0000, |114 0x0000, |115
> 0x0000, |116 0x0000, |117 0x0000, |118 0x0000, |119 0x0000, |120
> 0x0000, |121 0x0000, |122 0x0000, |123 0x0000, |124 0x0000, |125
> 0x0000, |126 0x0000, |127 0x0000, |128 0x0000, |129 0x0000, |130
> 0x0000, |131 0x0000, |132 0x0000, |133 0x0000, |134 0x0000, |135
> 0x0000, |136 0x0000, |137 0x0000, |138 0x0000, |139 0x0000, |140
> 0x0000, |141 0x0000, |142 0x0000, |143 0x0000, |144 0x0000, |145
> 0x0000, |146 0x0000, |147 0x0000, |148 0x0000, |149 0x0000, |150
> 0x0000, |151 0x0000, |152 0x0000, |153 0x0000, |154 0x0000, |155
> 0x0000, |156 0x0000, |157 0x0000, |158 0x0000, |159 0x0000, |160
> 0x0000, |161 0x0000, |162 0x0000, |163 0x0000, |164 0x0000, |165
> 0x0000, *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated Aborted (core
> dumped)

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `sizeof(buf_tx)` is the size in *bytes*. But your array is of 2-byte elements. And your loop really doesn't care about what was initialized and what was not.

Comment: `sizeof(buf_tx)/sizeof(buf_tx[0])` to get elements instead of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof` gives the number of bytes in its operand. In typical C implementations, `uint16_t` is two bytes, so `uint16_t buf_tx[101]` is 202 bytes.

To get the number of elements in an array `x`, use `sizeof x / sizeof *x`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof buf_tx / sizeof *buf_tx; i++)
```

This is often packaged in a macro:

```
#define NumberOf(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))
…
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOf(buf_tx); i++)
```

This works only for arrays, not for pointers, because `sizeof x` gives the size of the array if `x` is an array but the size of the pointer if `x` is a pointer. Notably, function parameters declared as arrays, such as `void foo(int x[])`, are automatically adjusted to be pointers, so `NumberOf(x)` will not work for them.

Comment: "In typical C implementations, uint16_t is two bytes", in which implementation is uint16_t not 2 bytes?

Comment: @StefanRiedel: In a C implementation in which `unsigned char` is 16 bits. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516044/system-where-1-byte-8-bit) The C standard only requires that character types such as `char` be at least 8 bits (by bounds it places on `UCHAR_MAX` and such), not that they be only 8 bits. In the C standard, “byte” is the size of the character types. So, in a C implementation with 16-bit characters, a byte would be 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array `array` then the number of elements in the array is determinate by this expression

```
sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array )
```

So in the loops you need to use this expression.

It is better to define a corresponding constant like

```
const size_t N = sizeof( buf_tx ) / sizeof( *buf_tx );
```

and use it in loops like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) buf_tx[i] = 0;
```

Or

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf("|%zu %#06x, ",i,buf_tx[i] );
}
```

Pay attention to that for objects of the type `size_t` you need to use the conversion specifier `%zu`. And instead of writing manually `0x` before the conversion specifier for outputted number you could use the flag `#` as `%#06x`.